# SQL - How to use PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a very complicated situation where I need to use a PIVOT statement on a vertical table and I would like to ask you help in order to achieve my objective.

My objective to create a stored procedure procedure with SQL Server 2008 with 2 parameters: Year & Month defined by user.

Then, I need my SQL statement return vertical Data into a very well formatted result:

- Based on the following example, this statement will return 5 different working weeks for the defined Year & Month
- For each week, this statement should return the list of information attached to it
- The Header of each week should be displayed as the following: 
  Apr 28 - May 04 
  May 05 - May 11 
  May 12 - May 18 
  May 19 - May 25 
  May 26 - June 01
- The header should contain the number of records / information per week. The value is presented inside "()"

```html
Information   Transaction_Date
---------------   ----------------
Information # 1   2014-04-28
Information # 2   2014-04-28
Information # 3   2014-04-28
Information # 4   2014-04-28
Information # 5   2014-04-29
Information # 6   2014-04-29
Information # 7   2014-04-29
Information # 8   2014-04-30
Information # 9   2014-04-30
Information # 10  2014-05-01
Information # 11  2014-05-01

Information # 12  2014-05-05
Information # 13  2014-05-05
Information # 14  2014-05-06
Information # 15  2014-05-06
Information # 16  2014-05-07
Information # 17  2014-05-07
Information # 18  2014-05-07
Information # 19  2014-05-08

Information # 20  2014-05-12
Information # 21  2014-05-12
Information # 22  2014-05-14
Information # 23  2014-05-14
Information # 24  2014-05-14
Information # 25  2014-05-14
Information # 26  2014-05-14
Information # 27  2014-05-16
Information # 28  2014-05-16
Information # 29  2014-05-16

Information # 30  2014-05-19
Information # 31  2014-05-19
Information # 32  2014-05-22
Information # 33  2014-05-22
Information # 34  2014-05-23
Information # 35  2014-05-24
Information # 36  2014-05-24

Information # 37  2014-05-26
Information # 38  2014-05-26
Information # 39  2014-05-26
Information # 40  2014-05-26
Information # 41  2014-05-26
Information # 42  2014-05-28
Information # 43  2014-05-28
Information # 44  2014-05-28
Information # 45  2014-05-29
Information # 46  2014-05-29
Information # 47  2014-05-29
Information # 48  2014-05-30
Information # 49  2014-05-31



Apr 28 - May 04 (11)  May 05 - May 11 (8)  May 12 - May 18 (10) May 19 - May 25 (7)  May 26 - June 01 (13)
--------------------  -------------------  -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Information # 1    Information # 12  Information # 20  Information # 30  Information # 37
Information # 2    Information # 13  Information # 21  Information # 31  Information # 38
Information # 3    Information # 14  Information # 22  Information # 32  Information # 39
Information # 4    Information # 15  Information # 23  Information # 33  Information # 40
Information # 5    Information # 16  Information # 24  Information # 34  Information # 41  
Information # 6    Information # 17  Information # 25  Information # 35  Information # 42  
Information # 7    Information # 18  Information # 26  Information # 36  Information # 43  
Information # 8    Information # 19  Information # 27        Information # 44
Information # 9          Information # 28        Information # 45
Information # 10         Information # 29        Information # 46
Information # 11                     Information # 47
                         Information # 48
                         Information # 49
```

Comment: What database are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Best resource I could find when I was learning PIVOTS was: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: @GoatCO I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I know how it works with basic examples of PIVOT. But I have a complex situation with dynamic columns & names and Total Number of records

Comment: Your requirements for dynamic columns pretty much mean you're forced to use dynamic SQL or a report writer that supports a pivot operation.